# Numpy ignoring frames of TIF file when converting from PIL

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library

I have 3 diemnsional image saved as a multi page tif file. I tried reading it in using PIL(low) and it detected the correct number of frames but when I convert it to numpy it ignores the frames and only converts the single page/layer.

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

pil_ = Image.open(path)
pil_.size # this outputs (1024, 512)
pil_.n_frames # this outputs the correct number of frames i.e. 21
num = np.array(pil_)
num.shape # this outputs (512, 1024)
```

Shouldnt the numpy array be a 3D array? How do I convert it so that the frames are also considered?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a thread here (https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2007-May/419217.html) which suggests that you may be able to manually seek through the frames and assign each one into the 3rd dimension of your numpy array.

Comment: Thanks, I tried that, but keep getting the error: ``ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (512,1024) into shape (1024,512)``. Dont know why its trying to transpose the dimensions.

Comment: That *is* strange.  You've tried to create the numpy zero array with transposed dimensions?

Comment: **PIL/Pillow** stores and refers to images using `[col,row]` whereas **numpy** uses `[row,col]`